# Type 'Object' is not assignable to type 'any[]' in Angular 4.x app

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I get the following error in my typescript code but unsure why any ideas - it is the `this.items` variable?

> Type 'Object' is not assignable to type 'any[]'.   The 'Object' type
>   is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any'
>   type instead?

```
export class GifpickerComponent implements OnInit {
    public searchTerm : FormControl = new FormControl();
    public items = [];

constructor(private gifpickerService: GifpickerService){
    this.searchTerm.valueChanges
        .subscribe(data => {
            this.gifpickerService.search(data).subscribe(response =>{
                console.log('subscribe', response);
                this.items = response; /* line picked up in error */
            })
        })
}
```

/* service as requested */

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from "../../services/api.service";
import { HttpClient,  HttpParams, HttpResponse} from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class GifpickerService {

constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private apiService: ApiService
) {}

search(term){
    console.log('term', term);
    let url = this.apiService.getApiUrl('gif/search');
    let params = new HttpParams()
        .set('q', String(term))
        .set('results_only', '1');

    return this.http.get(url, {params: params})
        .map(response => {
            return response;
        });
 }
}
```

Comment: can you show the implementation of your `search` method ? so we can demonstrate the best practice?

Comment: What is the type of `response`?

Comment: @Zabs you should type the `response`. For example if response is an array of SearchResult : `return this.http.get<SearchResult[]>(url, {params: params})`. By the way `map` after `get` is useless in your example. Then in component add typing to items: `public items: SearchResult[] = [];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do this change

```
public items = {}
```

then thing is, you are making items as array of `any` type and apparently response is of `object` type

Answer (score 1):

This is an array of any items `any[]`.

```
public items = []
```

Response is probably an object.

You are setting items to be equal to an object.

You should either make items of type any OR

You should push the response object to the items array like this:

```
this.items.push(response)
```

OR

```
this.items = [...this.items, response]
```

Depending on what you want.